# Create dictionary in class

Tags: python

First of all this may sound confusing because honestly i don't really understand the question my self and I am really sorry for that(and that's why I am asking this question).

So basically I have to write a code based on the given doc-stings, but I don't really understand what I have to do. Can someone please please help me with it?

This are the docstrings:

```
class Table():
'''A class to represent a SQuEaL table'''
def set_dict(self, new_dict):
    '''(Table, dict of {str: list of str}) -> NoneType

    Populate this table with the data in new_dict.
    The input dictionary must be of the form:
        column_name: list_of_values
    '''
    pass 

def get_dict(self):
    '''(Table) -> dict of {str: list of str}

    Return the dictionary representation of this table. The dictionary keys
    will be the column names, and the list will contain the values
    for that column.
    '''
```

Does anyone have any idea? Honestly, I've spend days just figuring it out but i just can't. 
Please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: so, what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're supposed to create a class `Table` that does the following:

implements a `get_dict` method such that `Table.get_dict()` returns a dictionary whose keys are the column headers and whose values are the rows for that column.

implements a `set_dict` method such that `Table.set_dict(some_dict)` will populate the table with the dictionary you pass it, to the same specifications as above.

If it will help, imagine a table:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
+--------------------------------------+
|C1R1    | C2R1    | C3R1    | C4R1    |
+--------------------------------------+
|C1R2    | C2R2    | C3R2    | C4R2    |
+--------------------------------------+
```

That would be represented by a dictionary of the form:

```
some_dict = {"Column1": ["C1R1", "C1R2"],
             "Column2": ["C2R1", "C2R2"],
             "Column3": ["C3R1", "C3R2"],
             "Column4": ["C4R1", "C4R2"]}
```

Your goal is to write a class `Table` such that:

```
table = Table()
table.set_dict(some_dict) # saves that dictionary
table.get_dict()          # produces that dictionary
```

Comment: First of all thank you soo much.I really appreciate this. But how do you know how many keys/value pair the dictionary has?

Comment: @Diana `len(dict)` is the number of keys in the dictionary, and `len(dict[some_key])` is how many values are in `dict[some_key]`. However you shouldn't need to know either of those values to implement this.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't? that's the part where i am really confused because your keys can be 5 or 200 ?

Comment: @Diana that's your homework assignment! Go and puzzle over it! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna end up something like this.

```
class Table():
    def set_dict(self, new_dict):
        self.dict = new_dict

    def get_dict(self):
        return self.dict or {}
```

Comment: If someone submitted that as a homework answer I would fail them. There are so many more things to consider.